# Unable to execute 'n' number of test cases in browserstack and real mobile through testNg.xml file using batch run

Tags: java, selenium, appium, browserstack

I'm getting this below error in browserstack and real mobile when i execute 'n' number of test cases in testNG.xml file through batch run, and executions are getting halted in the middle of test run

"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Appium error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

I've used device as Samsung Galaxy S8/Samsung Galaxy S9 and browser type Android chrome and appium verison v1.8.1

Comment: try updating your appium server to latest stable version

Comment: I tried by updating appium server to latest version v1.12.1 and executed some test cases, executions got halted in the middle of test runs and got the error like this "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I can help if you can share your code. Try to find out in which line the above error is occurring.